# Angular 1.5 get service value using Subject

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

I using angularjs version 1.5, objective is to use component to listen to service updates.

myService.ts

```
export class myService {
   private _myBoolean: Subject<boolean>

  constructor() {
   this._myBoolean = new Subject<boolean>();
  }
   //  
  public get myBoolean(): Observable<boolean>{
    return this._myBoolean;
  }

  public set myBoolean(value: Observable<boolean>) {
   this._myBoolean.onNext(true)
  }

}
```

I want to listen for boolean update from the service
myComponent

```
export class myComponent ContextComponent {
  public updatedBoolean;

  $inject: string[] = [myService]

  this.updatedBoolean = this.myService.myBoolean   <--- I need to subscribe to the service
}
```

I tryng to work with angularJS to subscribe to incoming updates from service to update my component variable.

Comment: What is not working? `export class myComponent ContextComponent` looks like a syntax error, you need `implements` or `extends` in there. Using `Observable` objects in angularjs probably wont work as you expect either, `Observable` is not automatically tied into the angular digest cycle, you'll have to kick off the digest cycle manually.

Comment: Is it possible to give an example using the above service and component with digest cycle?

Answer (score 0):

My guess you need to subscribe:

```
this.updatedBoolean = this.myService.myBoolean.subscribe(newVal => { yourChanges...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just bind the `Subject` to a variable in your component and expect angularjs to handle it automatically. Unlike the more modern Angular there is the concept of a digest cycle in angularjs, the digest cycle affects when changes to a scope are applied to the DOM. This is one of the reasons angularjs does not use the native `Promise`, the `$q` service implements a special type of promise that is integrated into the angularjs digest cycle. Since `Subject` (and `Observable` in general) postdates angularjs and there is no direct equivalent that hooks into the digest cycle *you* are responsible for working with the `Observable` and telling angularjs when to process the scope.

This is what that might look like:

```
export class MyComponent implements ng.IComponentController {

    public static $inject: string[] = [
        '$scope',
        'myService'
    ];

    public updatedBoolean: boolean;

    constructor(private readonly $scope: ng.IScope,
                private readonly myService: MyService) { }

    $onInit() {
        this.myService.myBoolean.subscribe((value) => {
            this.updatedBoolean = value;
            this.$scope.$digest();
        });
    }

}
```

Note: I'm not familiar with `ContextComponent` so I switched to using the "standard" angularjs types (e.g. `npm install @types/angular@1.5.x`) for this example.